# deleting <a> tag in th middle of othre tags

Tags: bash, sed, grep, find

I have several lines in html files that look like this:

```
<div class="thumb tright">
   <div class="thumbinner" style="width:302px;">
       <a href="https://example.com/en/File:Tools_my_settings.png" class="image">
          <img alt="" src="images_en/thumb/0/0a/tool_settings.png/9dd94c2d99eea9.png" width="300" height="110" class="thumbimage" srcset="/my/en/images_en/thumb/0/0a/my_settings.png/450px-my_settings.png 1.5x, /31/en/images_en/thumb/0/0a/my_settings.png/600px-my_settings.png 2x"/>
       </a> 
       <div class="thumbcaption">
           <div class="magnify">
              <a href="https://example.com/en/File:Tools_my_settings.png" class="internal" title="Enlarge"></a>
           </div>
           Tool settings
       </div>
    </div>
</div>Tools Features - So Far
```

I need to delete the following href and and the corresponding closing tag `</a>` immediately after the `.png 2x"/>` text element.

```
<a href="https://example.com/en/File:**Tools_my_settings.png" class="image">...</a>
```

at the end I need the line to look like this:

```
<div class="thumb tright">
    <div class="thumbinner" style="width:302px;">
        <img alt="" src="images_en/thumb/0/0a/tool_settings.png/9dd94c2d99eea9.png" width="300" height="110" class="thumbimage" srcset="/my/en/images_en/thumb/0/0a/my_settings.png/450px-my_settings.png 1.5x, /31/en/images_en/thumb/0/0a/my_settings.png/600px-my_settings.png 2x"/>
        <div class="thumbcaption">
            <div class="magnify">
                <a href="https://example.com/en/File:Tools_my_settings.png" class="internal" title="Enlarge"></a>
            </div>
            Tool settings
        </div>
    </div>
</div>Tools Features - So Far
```

All files contain the same patern:`<a href="https://choopy.com/en/File:`...
this is what I have tried:

```
find /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/lms_docs/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed 's/<a\shref="https:\/\/choopy.com\/en\/File:([--:\w?@%&+~#=]*[a-z])\.png"\sclass="image">//g'
```

but it doesn't do anything and i don't know how to delete the corresponding closing tag `</a>`

Comment: You don't want to substitute `https://choopy.com...`, aren't you? But your code is intended for that. You should delete link with `https://example.com...`, am I right?

Comment: sorry,I  fixed the original post...

Comment: Stock advice: do not try to process XML with line-oriented tools like `sed`. Use something like `xmlstarlet` or `xsltproc` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This will delete all `<a href>`'s to `https://...com` of an `image` class and the corresponding `</a>`:

```
find /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/lms_docs/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed '/<a href=\"https:\/\/.*\.com\/en\/File:.*\" class=\"image\">/,/<\/a>/{ /<a href=\"https:\/\/.*\.com\/en\/File:.*\" class=\"image\">/d; /<\/a>/d}'
```

And this one is for the specific domain, as `https://example.com`:

```
find /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/lms_docs/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed '/<a href=\"https:\/\/example\.com\/en\/File:.*\" class=\"image\">/,/<\/a>/{ /<a href=\"https:\/\/example\.com\/en\/File:.*\" class=\"image\">/d; /<\/a>/d}'
```

This works like this: "match all lines between `<a href`.... with `class` image and the corresponding `<\a>` (`sed` pattern matching: "/ /")
Then again, for the matched block do "{ }": match the same patterns and delete them "/d".

More info: [section 4.24](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq4.html)

Comment: I think, the comands in curly braces "{ }" could be simplified with the knowledge that the lines to delete are the first one and the last in the matched block.